# CakePHP Session, Not displaying on first refresh

Tags: session, cakephp, page-refresh

I am using CakePHP 1.3 latest version for my Administrator / User login.

I am facing a very weird issue, whenever I am trying to login using Auth, on first attempt it is not displaying me any information into `SESSION` but whenever I refresh the page again, all information is coming to Session.

Any ideas, why this happends?

Code is here from `app_controller.php` file

```
function beforeFilter()
{   
    $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
    $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email_address', 'password' => 'password');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.status' => '1','User.paymentstatus' => '0');
    if($this->Auth->User())
    {
        if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.user_type') == 3) {
            $this->layout = 'admin';
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'welcome');
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home');
        }
    }
}

function beforeRender(){
    $this->set('auth', $this->Auth->user());
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); // // HTTP/1.1
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: Mon, 17 Dec 2007 00:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
}
```

Earliest response would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Are you redirecting after successful login? You can't access session data (in `$_SESSION`) during the same request it is set.

Comment: yes i am redirecting to welcome page, once logged in, however when user login firsttime, it is not redirecting, and when i refresh page again, it redirects where it should go..

Comment: Okay, in that case it might be helpful if you could post the action that is doing to login/redirect so we can have a closer look.

Comment: FYI, as of CakePHP 1.3 you can [configure components in the `$components` array](http://book.cakephp.org/view/995/Configuring-Components).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> function beforeFilter(){   
>   parent::beforeFilter();
>   $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
>   $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email_address', 'password' => 'password');
>   $this->Auth->loginAction = array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
>   $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.status' => '1','User.paymentstatus' => '0');
>   if($this->Auth->user() && $this->Auth->user('user_type') == 3)
>         $this->layout = 'admin';
> }
> function login(){
>   if($this->Auth->user()){
>     if($this->Auth->user('user_type') == 3) {
>         $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'welcome'));
>     } else  {
>         $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
>     }
>   }
>  }
> ```

You don't have to set auth in beforeRender, you can still access that in the view with `$this->Session->read('Auth.User');`

Comment: Quite simply, as you have set `$this->Auth->autoRedirect = false`, you need to redirect manually in the `UsersController::login()` action (as shown in [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1274/autoRedirect)). Usually one would put `$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());`, but as your redirect URL differs the above code should meet your needs.